# Problems connecting Visual Studio 2022 and Oracle 21c

Tags: asp.net, json, oracle, .net-core

Hello and first of all I am trying to improve my English so some words may not be used correctly or I could use better words.

I just want to do an insert to test the correct configuration on the connection and on the insert.

Moving on to the question I'm having trouble creating the connection between visual studio 2022 in an asp.net core version 6 project code and oracle 21c. First, install Oracle Database Express Edition and then Oracle SQL Developer, then create a new project. Then use the server explorer to verify the connection using the "Prueba" database with the SYSTEM user as in the following image.

[image]

My appsettings.json file has the following configuration:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "SqlServerConnection": "Server=.; Database=Prueba; User ID=SYSTEM; Password=qwe123; Trust Server Certificate=true;",
        "OracleConnection": "User ID=SYSTEM; Password=qwe123; Pooling=true; Connection Timeout=120; Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));"
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using PruebaConexion.Models;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace PruebaConexion.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private IConfiguration _config;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = config;
        }



        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            Prueba();
            return View();
        }

        public void Prueba()
        {
            DbConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_config["ConnectionStrings:OracleConnection"]);
            connection.Open();
            DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into VEHICLE_PERSON ( EMP_NUMBER, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, " +
                "COSTCENTER, DEPARTMENT, CREDENT_NUMBER, NUMBER1, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE, RIGHTS1 ) " +
                "values ( 'Prueba', 'Carrasco', 'Leonardo', 'Prueba', 'Desarrollo', 'Prueba', " +
                "'Prueba', '10/10/2022', '11/11/2023', 'Prueba');";
        }

      

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

I have recently used the following code:

```
        public void Test2()
        {
            OracleConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder.DataSource = "localhost:1521/Prueba";
            builder.UserID = "SYSTEM";
            builder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
            builder.Password = "password";
            builder.ConnectionTimeout = 50;
            Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);

            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Conexión válida");
                    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT BANNER FROM v$version;", connection);
                    OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sin resultados.");
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                }
            }

        }
```

And in the console it shows the following:

[image]

When running the program it shows the following error:
`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'Connection request timeout.'`.
On the line with the following code:
`connection.Open();`.

If you need another file or a screenshot, do not hesitate to ask and I will update the question.

Comment: You may want to put an appropriate `oracle` tag on your question. It may attract knowledgeable eyes